# show existing navigation menu connected to one activity in another activity

Tags: android, android-activity, kotlin, android-navigationview

I am in the process of building an app and have a navigation menu in my first activity, however, when I go to the second it doesn't show, so which bits of code do I copy from my first activity for the navigation menu to show there too?

I have tried to copy what I thought was relevant bits of code from the first activity into the second, however that second activity crashed, so I tried to remove that added code and failed to reverse it, so I imported the code from a backup to get it working again.

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity(), NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener {


override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
    val toolbar: Toolbar = findViewById(R.id.toolbar)
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar)

    val fab: FloatingActionButton = findViewById(R.id.fab)
    fab.setOnClickListener { view ->
        val intent = Intent(this, Main2Activity::class.java)
        val sharedPref = this?.getPreferences(Context.MODE_PRIVATE)
        val mystr = sharedPref.getInt(getString(R.string.STR), 0)
        intent.putExtra("data", mystr)
        startActivity(intent)
    }
    val drawerLayout: DrawerLayout = findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout)
    val navView: NavigationView = findViewById(R.id.nav_view)
    val toggle = ActionBarDrawerToggle(
        this, drawerLayout, toolbar, R.string.navigation_drawer_open, R.string.navigation_drawer_close
    )
    drawerLayout.addDrawerListener(toggle)
    toggle.syncState()

    navView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(this)

    //val db = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance()
}

override fun onBackPressed() {
    val drawerLayout: DrawerLayout = findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout)
    if (drawerLayout.isDrawerOpen(GravityCompat.START)) {
        drawerLayout.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START)
    } else {
        super.onBackPressed()
    }
}

override fun onCreateOptionsMenu(menu: Menu): Boolean {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    menuInflater.inflate(R.menu.main, menu)
    return true
}

override fun onOptionsItemSelected(item: MenuItem): Boolean {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    return when (item.itemId) {
        R.id.action_settings -> true
        else -> super.onOptionsItemSelected(item)
    }
}

override fun onNavigationItemSelected(item: MenuItem): Boolean {
    // Handle navigation view item clicks here.
    when (item.itemId) {
        R.id.nav_home -> {
            // Handle the camera action
            val i = Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("https://www.facebook.com/brobostigon/"))
            startActivity(i)
        }
        R.id.nav_gallery -> {
            val intent = Intent(this, MainActivity::class.java)
            startActivity(intent)
        }
        R.id.nav_slideshow -> {
            val intent = Intent(this, Main2Activity::class.java)
            startActivity(intent)
        }
        R.id.nav_tools -> {

        }
        R.id.nav_share -> {
            val i = Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("http://taylorworld.me.uk/privacy-policy.html"))
            startActivity(i)
        }
        R.id.nav_send -> {

        }
    }
    val drawerLayout: DrawerLayout = findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout)
    drawerLayout.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START)
    return true
}
```

Here is my second activity

```
class Main2Activity : AppCompatActivity() {

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main2)
        //val mystr: Int = intent.getIntExtra("data", 0)
        //editText8.setText(Integer.toString(mystr))
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is is not feasible. You have to make separate navigation drawer on each activity and this is not feasible.

Instead you can use fragments, even you need to use fragments with navigation drawer if you want to keep same navigation drawer on different layouts too.

Comment: I have used the add new fragment function within android studio, and am getting the following errors. https://pastebin.com/sScUaM1x

Comment: Your question contains very long answer same as a tutorial. So here is one example of navigation drawer with fragments. Follow [this link](https://www.simplifiedcoding.net/android-navigation-drawer-example-using-fragments/).

Comment: I got fragments working, i imported my existing layouts into two fragments to test it out, https://photos.app.goo.gl/xbLGdzEbG7JWa8tq7 , and it has certainly worked, i just need to work out now how to firstly on load of the activity show only one fragment, and second work out how to ok click of items in the nav drawer change between fragments.

Comment: either set background and clickable=true on root element of fragment layout. Or try replacing fragment on navigation button click.

Comment: android:clickable="true" android:focusable="true" android:background="@drawable/ic_launcher_background"   so adding something like that into content_main.xml into the constraintlayout but not in the fragments?

Comment: No you need to add it on all fragments' layout root element.

Comment: https://imagebin.ca/v/4lGF4wynAgq6 that has definitely made just one fragment show at once. :)

Answer (score 0):

val fragmentManager = supportFragmentManager                                                                                                  val fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction()
val fragment = TitleFragment()                                                                                                                 val fragment2 = MiscFragment()                                                                                                                fragmentTransaction.add(R.id.contentlayout, fragment)
fragmentTransaction.remove(fragment2)                                                                                                                                                                                                              fragmentTransaction.commit()

I put that in my mainactivity oncreate(), with the thinking when the activity loads it forces it to load a specific fragment, and only that fragment. contentlayout is the ID of the layout to which that will be applied, ie in my case it is the constraintlayout in content_main.xml.

Answer (score 0):

check AndroidManifest.xml (app/manifests/AndroidManifest.xml), find correct activity and check line android:theme="@style/... />